# Cygwin SSH connection refused. Used to work now does not

Tags: networking, ssh, cygwin, putty

I am trying to SSH to my iDevice (jailbroken) and it used to work. Yet now I get this:

```
$ ssh root@192.168.0.25 -v
OpenSSH_7.2p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g 1 Mar 2016
debug2: resolving "192.168.0.25" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.25 [192.168.0.25] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 192.168.0.25 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.25 port 22: Connection refused
```

Really not sure what to do. I have reinstalled SSH on both devices. Using cygwin terminal on windows 8.

Also used Putty using SSH and another try on TELNET same error.

The IP is the correct one. SSH was working yesterday it now no longer is.

Answer (score 1):

A firewall somewhere is blocking the connection, -OR- the sshd process is no longer running on the target machine.

If you rebooted, your firewall daemon may have restarted if you had stopped it manually.

Ensure there's an exception for TCP port 22 to allow the ssh traffic.

Ensure you can PING the target machine.